# Unable to create Root Module: config {...config/strict_checkstyle.xml}, classpath {null}

Tags: gradle, checkstyle

We have a Gradle script that runs Checkstyle:

```
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

checkstyle {
    configFile rootProject.file('config/strict_checkstyle.xml')
    ignoreFailures false
    showViolations true
    toolVersion = rootProject.ext.checkstyleVersion
}

task Checkstyle(type: Checkstyle) {
    configFile rootProject.file('config/strict_checkstyle.xml')
    source 'src'
    ignoreFailures false
    showViolations true
    include '**/*.java'
    classpath = files()
}

// adds checkstyle task to existing check task
afterEvaluate {
    if (project.tasks.getByName("check")) {
        check.dependsOn('checkstyle')
    }
}
```

with this `strict_checkstyle.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
        "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.2//EN"
        "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_2.dtd">

<module name="Checker">

    <module name="FileLength"/>
    <module name="FileTabCharacter"/>

    <module name="TreeWalker">

        <module name="SuppressionXpathFilter">
            <property name="file" value="config/app_checkstyle_suppressions.xml"/>
            <property name="optional" value="false"/>
        </module>

        <module name="SuppressionXpathFilter">
            <property name="file" value="config/api_checkstyle_suppressions.xml"/>
            <property name="optional" value="false"/>
        </module>


        <!-- Checks for imports -->
        <!-- See http://checkstyle.sf.net/config_import.html -->
        <module name="AvoidStarImport"/>
        <module name="IllegalImport"/>
        <module name="RedundantImport"/>
        <module name="UnusedImports"/>

        ...
```

As you can see we have setup a suppression baseline for our two gradle modules `app` and `api`. This works on our CI machine and all of our dev machines except one. He is getting this error:

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':module:Checkstyle'.
> Unable to create Root Module: config {/Users/user/our_application/config/strict_checkstyle.xml}, classpath {null}.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Running with `--stacktrace` shows the problem:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':component:Checkstyle'.
...
Caused by: : Unable to create Root Module: config {/Users/user/our_application/config/strict_checkstyle.xml}, classpath {null}.
...
Caused by: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to find: config/app_checkstyle_suppressions.xml
...
Caused by: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: Unable to find: config/app_checkstyle_suppressions.xml
...
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/user/.gradle/daemon/5.1.1/config/app_checkstyle_suppressions.xml (No such file or directory)
```

Either Checkstyle or Gradle is looking in the user's *sytem* gradle directory, not w/in our own application's directory. So we had the developer update the checkstyle.xml with the full path:

```
   <module name="SuppressionXpathFilter">
            <property name="file" value="/Users/user/our_application/config/app_checkstyle_suppressions.xml"/>
            <property name="optional" value="false"/>
        </module>
```

Then everything works fine. So why is Checkstyle / Gradle not recognizing that `config/app_checkstyle_suppressions.xml` is the correct relative path? Why would this happen only on one dev machine?

Comment: Checkstyle always uses the path as it is given. If you give it a relative path, it uses a relative path. See https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/java/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/utils/CommonUtil.java#L488 . I can only assume gradle is changing to the system directory.